# 2013 Macbook Air can't get past grey screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, hardware, recovery, macos

We were camping, I was trying to pull up a movie and it froze. It was completely unresponsive, I didn't see the kernel panic message but I forced a restart by holding down the power button.
On booting again, it went straight to the "prohibitory symbol." I forced another restart, and since then, the screen has just been grey. No Apple logo, nothing.
After 30-45 minutes, I get the flashing question mark folder.

I have reset the SMC and NVRAM. Resetting the NVRAM seems to work, it does the startup chime, the screen flashes, and then shortly after it chimes again. It didn't help.

I can't boot into recovery <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>., Internet recovery <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, or diagnostics <kbd>D</kbd>. Safe mode <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>
and single-user mode <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> didn't work either.

I have tried booting off of a Lubuntu flash drive <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and a SliTaz live CD via a USB CD drive <kbd>C</kbd>; neither of  those did anything either. If I leave it for a while, the flash drive will start blinking and the CD spins up, but the computer is still grey and unresponsive. I have a Mac at work, so I might try creating a bootable flash drive from that once I go back.

I've ordered one of their cursed pentalobe screwdrivers; does anyone know if this machine has diagnostic LEDs like the older iMacs? I'm thinking it's definitely a hardware issue at this point but I don't know how to move forward, I figure I can at least recover the SSD.

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need any other details. I haven't seen anything like this before.

I *think* it was running 10.8 or 10.9 but I don't know for sure, I haven't really used it in a couple years. Model is A1466, EMC 2632.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... does anyone know if this machine has diagnostic LEDs like the older iMacs?

There are no diagnostic LEDs on the logic board.

> I'm thinking it's definitely a hardware issue at this point but I don't know how to move forward, I figure I can at least recover the SSD.

This is a big jump in determination when two very conspicuous clues were presented:

- A prohibitory symbol means that it cannot find a boot volume

  - [Fix a sometimes happening prohibitory sign 🚫](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352964/119271)
  - [No entry sign on 2017 Macbook Pro--will replacing the hard disk work?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392153/119271)
  - [Can't format my Macbook, HDD and mac Utilities won't load, “blocked” sign after trying to boot usb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271683/119271)
- A folder with a flashing question mark means the file system on the boot volume was corrupted.

  - [Unable to boot up my Mac. Getting a flashing folder with a question mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177972/119271)
  - [iMac only show flashing folder with question mark after formatting OS X partition drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236749/119271)
  - [Not seeing my HD in the disk utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86548/119271)

Now, I'm not ruling out hardware - it's entirely possible your drive has failed.  But breaking out the screwdriver prior to doing any sort of diagnostics or even examining the symptoms a bit more is putting the cart before the horse.  You can run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/HT202731) by holding <kbd>D</kbd>  while booting from a powered off state.

Comment: I tried running Apple Diagnostics, nothing. On AC power and on battery. Option-D to start it over the Internet doesn't work either.

Comment: Shift Cmd Opt R.  If you can’t boot that, it’s your logic board

Comment: That didn't work either. Guess it's the logic board, thanks for your help.